# Are moderators afraid to deal with users with high reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, declined-flags

I have noticed that when it comes to reviewing flags for answers from high reputation users, moderators are afraid to remove them.

They either [decline them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5931295/1090562) (I flagged it as a link only and got: "*a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*", which sounds strange), or completely [ignore them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5915167/1090562)<sup>†</sup>, but in almost a week no one has had the courage to do something with it.

So are moderators really afraid of dealing with high-rep users, and if it is the case, what can be changed to mitigate this problem?

<sup>†</sup><sub>I flagged that last one as a joke, because based on my point of view, answers are not a place for jokes, and if someone thinks that Stack Overflow cannot survive without a fun part, he can add it as a comment.</sub>

Comment: The second one was probably just not seen yet or ignored because it was asked so long ago that it is not really a problem.

Comment: Just to point out the answer was posted on May 6 2011 and this is only the second time someone has flagged it up. This isn't to say your question is invalid, but in terms of the real dross we have to deal with this doesn't come particularly high.

Comment: Show me a few legitimate flags on posts from high-rep users, and I'll show you how afraid I am.

Comment: I can say that I don't look at the rep of the user on the answer when I make a decision about what to do.

Comment: @ChrisF A non-answer like http://stackoverflow.com/a/5915167 shouldn't need to be flagged twice. Yes, technically you can say that it's a wrong answer, but come on, it's disruptive, useless, and even the author acknowledges that it isn't actually meant to be an answer.

Comment: *"in almost a week no one had a courage to do something with it"* - For the record, there are currently 500+ flags in the queue, many of which have been there longer than yours. Courage has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: ah, so my posts, say, get flagged and moderators are afraid of me and decline the flags. Much more likely than perhaps the OP here flagging the wrong things and high-rep users being far more experienced in not posting flaggable content, of course.

Comment: @Gilles - Maybe so, however, I was failing to point out that in it's 3+ year life only two people have found it flag worthy.

Comment: @ChrisF We hate fun, so we better delete it!

Comment: @ChrisF my question is why should people flag useless answer twice? Does flagging once is not enough to realize that a joke is not good enough to be an answer? This answer shows a bad example. Someone can see that he can get 100 upvotes with a joke and he might try to make more jokes here.

Comment: @MichaelMyers I think at least a hundred of those flags are the fault of me and a few friends... *shhhhh* ...

Comment: Far more than 100, @Cupcake.  You are killing us!

Comment: @SalvadorDali - I can't answer why it the previous flag was dealt with the way it was. My point is that until this year **no one** found the answer flag worthy. It's not that the answer is from a high rep user, it's that the answer is **old**.

Comment: I don't think it's fear of high rep users so much as the fact that there are some old off-topic questions and answers that are highly upvoted and doing no harm, so they are not priority for cleanup.

Comment: @bluefeet everyone should be glad that I only get 100 flags to use per day `:P`

Comment: @RobertHarvey please take a look at two flags I posted in my question. I think they are pretty legit.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: because I misread your post, is why. On first reading it sounded as if you felt flags *from you* were not handled because you have a high rep. Or some such. I was wrong.

Comment: The XKCD one actually [makes a good point](http://search.dilbert.com/comic/Random%20Number%20Generator).  That answer is pretty old, and several moderators have already looked at it.  What has changed that it now requires forcible removal by a mod?

Comment: @MartijnPieters please edit my question, if it is ambiguous (I tried to make it as clear as possible), but apparently I failed.

Comment: @Cupcake Yes, but so do the rest of us. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do not think that it is good enough to be qualified as an answer. XKCD has more than a few thousand comics that most make some sense in terms of programming. And I highly doubt you would like to see them as answers. Such answers invite new users to answer in a similar way, and therefore I think jokes are suited as comments, not an answers.

Comment: It doesn't have to be stellar, it just has to be an answer.  Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Comment: If it makes you feel better, a good portion of those hundreds of flags @Cupcake mentioned are on posts by high-rep users. And we've deleted the vast majority of them.

Comment: As @BoltClock said, mods have handled hundreds of flags on high rep users in the past few days itself and their posts have been deleted. The number of flags we are talking isn't a hyperbole. The only way to mitigate your issue is to raise valid flags.

Comment: What's wrong with the first answer?  It's short, but it gives plenty enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Ain't sure about high rep users but _each_ being on this Earth is afraid of me!

Comment: [Another fun and well known answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5915167/870604) from old SO days has been deleted thanks to meta, great job, thanks for cleaning up the site! /sarcasms

Comment: Why would moderators be afraid of high reputation users? Let's say a moderator made a high rep user angry - what could that user do?

Comment: I think your fear that joke answers will encourage new users to also post joke answers is unfounded. In practice most questions don't really set up for a punchline, and those that do don't always get a joke answer. So this is not a situation likely to get out of control. In my opinion "successful" joke answers like that "guaranteed random" one are _good_ for the site - what's wrong with an occasional bit of humour? Time spent policing joke answers could be better spent policing actual _bad_ (incorrect or misleading) answers.

Comment: @nnnnnn there is nothing wrong in jokes. And there is a specific place for such jokes - it is in the comment. As for wrong answers - moderators do not want to remove them. I you can see discussion and my opinion about this [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267952/1090562)

Comment: In my opinion some jokes only work as answers, not comments, and I have no problem with those being posted. It doesn't happen often, but it does happen.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

First off, *don't ask questions in flags*:

> How can this joke be here as a real answer?

...not even rhetorical ones. If an answer is a joke, please just say "this answer is a joke" or better yet "this is a joke answer which does nothing to help anyone solve a real problem and may confuse casual readers". Your flag might still be declined if the moderator disagrees, but at least it doesn't appear that you're expecting a reply rather than describing a real problem. And yes, folks frequently do try to ask questions via flags. No, it never ends well.

Beyond that, I suspect you're confusing two different things: high rep authors and high-scoring *posts*. In my opinion, moderators *should* be a bit reluctant to remove the latter - and when they do, they should do so because the flagged post presents a clear problem that cannot be resolved any other way. Remember, you're asking them to stand up to people who by voting asked the moderator to represent their interests and say, "upvotes aside, it is not in your best interest for this post to remain visible on the site".

Oh yeah - and it *is* the moderators who'll have to say that. You won't. Your name won't appear anywhere on the post; as a flagger, your participation is anonymous to everyone involved *except* for the moderators. The responsibility for deleting something with craploads of upvotes falls solely on their shoulders, and if they get it wrong "some random guy flagged it" ain't gonna cut it as an explanation.

So what can **you** change? First off, *vote!* You know, those up and down arrows next to the posts you're flagging. They matter. Then, [earn the privilege to delete stuff yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), and use it wisely - be willing to back up your actions if called on them, going out of your way to justify them. Finally, if you're really serious about this... Put your money where your mouth is and nominate yourself in the next election.

In other words, if you don't like how the moderators handle things, then be prepared to handle them yourself. As a moderator would, not as an anonymous flagger.

Comment: Thank you for amazing answer. It handles everything: - shows what I have done wrong, how should I do it better, why moderators might be reluctant and makes me feel in their skin. Thank you for this work.

Comment: [Why are the moderators being so strict with quality related flags recently?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160755/165773) -- wonder if these considerations still apply

Comment: Not really, @gnat. For flags like VLQ (must be obvious trash) or NAA (must clearly make no attempt to answer the question) this applies, but the outcome of "other" is entirely up to the moderator handling it - the rule there is always simply, "have a real problem, communicate it effectively".

Answer (score 35):

I declined the flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5931295/1288), which consists of:

> Use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) inside.

I declined it because you flagged it as "link only answer" but according to the guidelines laid out in [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/1288), that is (just barely) an answer, so we shouldn't delete it.

> See, this **is** an answer:
>
> [image: You probably want a FileOutputStream]

So no, I didn't decline the flag because I fear high-rep users. (I didn't notice the user's reputation, and I honestly don't know who that is. We don't post in the same tags often.)

Comment: I clearly remember that I flagged it as **other** and add a description: link only answer. I have not found anything better in the popup.

Comment: @SalvadorDali You're right, you did flag it as "link only answer." I'll edit my reply.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @ChrisF. I don't want Cupcake flagging me!

Comment: For Chris sake, what Cupcake has been doing that mods are afraid?!

Comment: Contributing to the onset of [flag diabetes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269120/are-moderators-afraid-to-deal-with-high-reputation-users#comment81061_269120), @bras

Comment: Piling up more work for the already overworked mods @braso. Mods have stopped eating cupcakes now.

Comment: @Shog: 100 flags per day are too less. We want more! `:)`

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion you know what they say, "Mo cakes, mo problems." No more flags though please...I might never stop. I still need to bake in the oven at least once a day, you know. Helps keep me nice and fresh in the morning.

Comment: Is it acceptable to convert answers like that to a comment?

Comment: @thefourtheye No, not if it's an answer.