# Dealing with wrong answers which may lead into learning

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I was seeing this [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3526324/1162884), which led me to think about answers that are wrong, but may lead into learning because of the discussion about the answer. Without entering on details at the given example, the discussion is about the following contradictions:

- The wrong answer may lead into deficit on reputation for the author, but deleting it from the topic may lead into loss of information. As deficit on reputation indicates that the answer do not contribute for the topic, this may lead for a decision on the answer author in this direction.
- However, down-voting is expected, as the answer is wrong itself, what is constructive is the discussion about why the answer is wrong.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267773/1162884) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267774/1162884) answers tell about the actual way to deal with it. Someone comment on the answer saying it is wrong (possibly downvoting it as well), and it is expected that the answer author will fix it or delete it. But even if the author fix it, normally people won't remove their downvotes in the answer after the fixing, which may lead to loss of information due to the answer deletion.

For this reason, it seems that adding a field like: **why the answer is wrong** may contribute with information, as may learning happen from mistakes **you and other make**. On this way, it should be given an opportunity for people to upvote the field **why the answer is wrong** if they think that the information helped they learn, and the upvotes would help with reputation the answer guy also (with low reputation, i.e. 1 rep per vote, and 5 for the guy which fulfilled the **why the answer is wrong** field). Also, when the answer author check the **why the answer is wrong**, it would make impossible to downvote the answer, maybe even negating any deficit reputation he had on the answer he made.

Of course, multiples wrong answer with the same mistake should be removed, as they do not contribute with information.

So, I think that the discussion is different from [other topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267772/answers-which-are-wrong) because it concerns to possibly create a better way to keep information which is wrong, but present it in a way that it will lead into learning. I've put my idea about how I think it would be fair, but as the title says, it is not about only what I think it would be fair, but to discuss about it.

Of course, keeping it the "way it is" is not that bad, but it seems that the way to present (and keep) this information may be improved. If it is possible or not is another thing.

Comment: I thought about a "critique" feature-request for here for a while now, but came to the same conclusions as Louis Answer for this. This site is just not a good fit for such things. We are here to have correct answers, if they happen to include common mistakes along the way, thats good, but the common mistake alone is just not enough.

Comment: People say that learning from your mistakes is better than getting the correct answer. So I think you're right. SO should have more feedback on what is wrong instead on primarily focusing on what is right. Though it's a tough border to walk on succesfully.

Answer (score 5):

I do not agree that we need this feature.

First, I'd say the only mistakes that are worth getting explained are those that are *common*. We don't need explanations to every odd mistake.

Second, there is a way to keep the explanation around and for someone to get reputation for it: **post it as part of a correct answer**. I do this when I can either foresee a common mistaken approach to solving a problem. ("You'd think that calling `foo()` would work but it won't because ... You must call `bar()` instead.") I also do this if I post an answer after someone else has posted an incorrect answer.

Third, and perhaps most importantly, **your proposal as currently stated encourages posting guesses.** Think about it. If I post a correct answer, I get reputation. If I post an incorrect answer, someone will correct me to get rep and I'll *still* get reputation. I win either way.

Fourth, this feature would certainly open a new arena for disputes among users, which you are not handling in your proposal. You post an answer, and I post a "why the answer is wrong" thingy. But, heck, I did not have my coffee that morning so I was wrong. Now you have to somehow dispute this erroneous post of mine. Even if you add some rules by which disputes can be handled, I doubt you can arrive at a proposal that won't just lead to a net increase in flags that will require moderator attention.

Comment: Which mistakes are not common? There are a lot of common things behind uncommon mistakes. Learning from these patters are valuable. Also I think you can say that this idea would lead to problems, like you do, but then you should also look at the upside of it. People fail 90% of the time, only succeed a fraction of the time. Thinking about the upside potential of showing people what is wrong with 90% could learn them more than the correct answer could ever do. And I think that that is exactly what StackOverflow is for, helping people in their understanding. Not only about the correct answer.

Comment: Well, this feature wouldn't imply that the wrong answers are needed to be explained. You might think that are errors that are unworthy to be explained, others may want to explain those errors you don't want to explain. I think that the answer author would have to approve the answer fixing, as you check the correct answer yourself. By doing it, you would lose any deficit in reputation in your answer.

Comment: I think that people that post guesses will do that anyway. Guesses should be posted in comments, and people that use this site in a good way will probably continue using the comments even if there is such mechanism. I don't feel like people will do like: "let me post anything here that may work as an answer so that someone can fix it letter if I am wrong".  I would say that people use this site as they like to feel good for solving problems and for helping others. Maybe for the rep as well. People won't post a guess as it is not even an answer and others will not even correct it, but flag it.