# Should I edit this old, incorrect, accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, specific-answer

I found this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971668/3670132) which, despite being accepted, is wrong. I won't trouble you with the boring JS part, but the `~~` operator acts like a *truncate* function, not a *floor*, which may lead to people reading the answer and misunderstanding what `~~` really does, possibly inducing bugs in their algorithms (for negative numbers).

There is a comment pointing out that mistake but is buried under a lot of other comments.

I have read another question in the meta SO ([Answers which are wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267772/answers-which-are-wrong)), but the answer is old, and the author seems inactive, and will likely not edit their answer.

Should I edit the answer with the correct behavior (since people rarely reads the comments), or leave it as is?

Comment: I wouldn't call that answer wrong. It just doesn't mention a restriction. I wouldn't edit it since there are already other answers that state the negative number problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the +280 comment can be converted to an edit with proper attribution. For example:-

> As @RightSaidFriend says:
>
> > Worth noting that it differs from `.floor()` in that it actually just
> >     removes anything to the right of the decimal. This makes a difference
> >     when used against a negative number. Also, it will always return a
> >     number, and will never give you NaN. If it can't be converted to a
> >     number, you'll get 0.

The number of comments is ... a confusing experience, some or all of them can disappear. After your edit, you can flag a comment (or a comment chain via a custom flag) for removal.

Comment: I have done this many times in the past (almost always for comments by the answer author) -- edit a substantial or length comment response into the answer and then flag said comment (and any related ones) for deletion. Moderators thus far have tended to mark such flags as helpful.